# How to access QNetworkReply->readAll()?

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork, qnetworkreply

I am making a simple get request via the QNetwork access manager, I send the request in the following function (the manager is initiated in the constructor).

```
void ui_screen::check_api_authenciation(const QString& access_token) {
    //construct the api url
    QUrl api_validation_url(this->API_VALIDATION_URL);
    QNetworkRequest api_validation_request(api_validation_url);
    api_validation_request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ServerHeader, "Authorization: token " + access_token);
    mgr->get(api_validation_request);
    connect(mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(on_authenciation_response_arrive(QNetworkReply*)));


}
```

and try to receive in the following function

```
void ui_screen::on_authenciation_response_arrive(QNetworkReply* reply) {

    QByteArray bts = reply->readAll();
    QString str(bts);
    ui->authenciation_progress->setRange(0,100);
    ui->authenciation_progress->setValue(100);
    ui->authenciation_progress_label->setText("Reply arrived");
}
```

but `reply->readAll()` triggers the following error

> error: member access into incomplete type 'QNetworkReply'

Why couldn't I access the member function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is raised if you're missing some include files.

You can include the declaration from header file for the `QNetworkReply` class that will "complete" the type by adding

```
#include <QNetworkReply>
```

at the top of your file.

Comment: Thanks, how foolish i became, thanks a lot.